# How to open photo gallery by clicking a button from a camera overlay?

Tags: android, ios, camera, titanium, appcelerator

I'm working with Titanium SDK 3.1.2 and deploying for iOS and Android.
You can find the code for my overlay [HERE](http://pastebin.com/XWE5ywGv). I did this because the code is large and wanted my question to be clean and clear.
I'm trying to create my own overlay for the camera with the following functions:
Take a picture.
Show video camera.
Open gallery.
Close camera.
I'm able to close the camera and take a picture, but I'm unable to open the photo gallery. My galleryButton has a singletap event like this:

```
galleryButton.addEventListener("singletap", function(e){
        openKineduPhotoGallery();
        Ti.Media.hideCamera();
    });
```

But nothing happens when I do this and after that I'm not able to close the camera nor take a picture. If I try to take a picture I get the following error:

```
Script Error {
        backtrace = "#0 () at file://localhost/var/mobile/Applications/79D9256C-7782-4323-A371-1AD45B37D037/Full.app/ui/common/GenericWindow.js:1\n#1 () at file://localhost/var/mobile/Applications/79D9256C-7782-4323-A371-1AD45B37D037/Full.app/ui/common/CreateMoment.js:1";
        line = 1;
        message = "'null' is not an object (evaluating 'o.type')";
        name = TypeError;
        sourceId = 81147840;
        sourceURL = "file://localhost/var/mobile/Applications/79D9256C-7782-4323-A371-1AD45B37D037/Full.app/ui/common/GenericWindow.js";
    }
```

I can't figure out what object is turning null for this to appear.
I tried to swap the order in which I called the methods to make it look like this:

```
galleryButton.addEventListener("singletap", function(e){
        Ti.Media.hideCamera();
        openKineduPhotoGallery();
    });
```

But that just hides the camera and doesn't show the gallery at all, plus I get the following warning in iOS:

```
Nov  6 18:37:20 Nenvo-iPod Full[3240] <Warning>: *** Assertion failure in -[UIWindowController transition:fromViewController:toViewController:target:didEndSelector:], /SourceCache/UIKit/UIKit-2380.17/UIWindowController.m:211
Nov  6 18:37:20 Nenvo-iPod Full[3240] <Warning>: Warning: Attempt to dismiss from view controller <UIImagePickerController: 0x1e5e17a0> while a presentation or dismiss is in progress!
```

I thought it was the hideCamera method fault so I commented that but that just triggers the error function on the showCamera method and I get a JSON error object like this:

```
{
  "type": "error",
  "code": 1,
  "source": [object MediaModule],
  "success": false
}
```

I tried to stringify MediaModule but it just returned an empty object.
Is it even possible to open the gallery from a camera overlay? What are my options? I'm trying to achieve a workflow similar to how instagram takes pictures, records video and selects a picture from gallery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to answer for below problem is actually when you call hideCamera and open PhotoGallery then both are opened as modal window so we need to call openKineduPhotoGallery function after friction of seconds.

```
galleryButton.addEventListener("singletap", function(e){
        Ti.Media.hideCamera();
        openKineduPhotoGallery();
});
```

so you should try the below code.

```
   galleryButton.addEventListener("singletap", function(e){
            Ti.Media.hideCamera();
            setTimeout(function(){
                    openKineduPhotoGallery();                   
            },500);
    });
```

Comment: nice approach, but still there's some lag between changing from camera to gallery and sometimes it crashes, hope I can find a better way

Comment: you can try to increase time from 500 to 1000 to test.

Comment: what I meant with lag is that the camera is closed and the window that was being displayed before is shown and then the gallery is opened, it might give the wrong impression to the user (as if the gallery crashed ).